# ASP.NET simple paging links

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, paging

Paging implemented in SP:
From SQL SP I get 12 rows per page out of 100s of rows. 
I also get "TotalCount = COUNT(*) OVER()".

If I have 100 rows and SP sends 12 rows per page how can I implement paging links on the page showing 12 rows per page?

page links similar to:
[Previous] [1],[2],[3] [Next]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    CountRecordsTotal = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("CountOverAll")
    Next
    End If

    TotalPages = (CountRecordsTotal / 12)
    If TotalPages = 0 Then
        TotalPages = TotalPages + 1
    End If

    Max = PageNumber + 1
    If Max >= TotalPages Then
        Max = TotalPages
    End If

    Min = PageNumber - 1
    If Min <= 1 Then
        Min = 1
    End If

    PrevPage = PageNumber - 1
    If PrevPage <= 1 Then
        PrevPage = 1
    End If

    NextPage = PageNumber + 1
    If NextPage >= TotalPages Then
        NextPage = TotalPages
    End If


<ul class="pagination matches_bottom_page">
<li><a class="page_prv_nxt" href="matches.aspx?pn=<%=PrevPage%>"><i 
class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Previous&nbsp;</a>
</li>
<% For index As Integer = Min To Max %>
<li>
<a class="page-link" href="matches.aspx?pn=<%=index%>"><%=index%></a>
</li>
<% Next %>
<li><a class="page_prv_nxt" href="matches.aspx?pn=
<%=NextPage%>">&nbsp;Next&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-
hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<ul>
```